# Can i pass a JSON object data values into a constant using it under useState in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks, constants

I have a JSON object say something like below from a local JSON file:

```
export default [
    {
        name: "Fredrick"
        age: 25,
        country: "Germany"
    },
    {
        name: "Jhonny"
        age: 28,
        country: "USA"
    },
    {
        name: "Meera"
        age: 26,
        country: "India"
    }
]
```

Now, how can I set it such that I can assign it within the below constant and use it within useState replacing the below hardcoded data ?

```
 const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(
[
        {
            name: "Fredrick"
            age: 25,
            country: "Germany"
        },
        {
            name: "Jhonny"
            age: 28,
            country: "USA"
        },
        {
            name: "Meera"
            age: 26,
            country: "India"
        }
]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PS: Cannot comment due to reputation.*

Its simple,

1. Whenever you want to use data or constants from other files, you simply import them.

> import jsonData from "./filePath/fileName";

2. Now simply, you can assign it to the useState like

> const [data, setData] = useState(jsonData);

*In case **your state** is still null*

You can define a useEffect to set the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if( !data ) {
   setData(jsonData)
 }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if the question was too silly/basic.. I'm learning React and new to it.

Comment: no problem, I am also learning. Keep learning and helping others <3